# What's the difference between data definition language and data description language?

Tags: ddl

Are they the same thing? Which one does DDL stand for? Here's what my understanding is, but could potentially be incorrect:

Data definition language:
Contains names and types and field length etc. of the attributes in a table

A database about a database - stores metadata

DBMS refer to these during the running and maintenance of a db

Data description language:

Function used by RDBMS to craete a database from nothing

Defines a database's table using Validation rules, field types, auto-incrementing requirements, primary kets etc.

Results in a final table design, aka  a schema

It's likely that I've gotten it all messed up, would appreciate some wisdom on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**DDL** (Data Definition Language): Used for defining data structures and schema like `CREATE` and `ALTER` commands.

**DML** (Data Manipulation Language): Used for managing data with schema objects like `SELECT` commands.

**DCL** (Data Control Language): Used to control data like `REVOKE` and `GRANT` commands.

**TCL** (Transaction Control Language): Used to manage the changes made by DML statements like `COMMIT`.

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803047/why-are-sql-statements-divided-into-ddl-dml-dcl-and-tcl-statements/12803155#12803155)